# Smooth transition between two states (dynamically generated)

Tags: android, animation, graphics

I have a graphic element. Let's give an initial state.

*Defining state*: a position on the screen and a custom transformation (scale+rotation+skew) given by the coordonates of 3 corners of the image (top-left, top-right and bottom-left).

And on a moment in time later the app recieves some input giving a new state. At this moment I need the graphical element to start a transition towards the new state, doing a natural transition (not to appear big distortion in the proportions of the element).

[image: Transition example]

Additionally, if a new state is recieved before the transition is over, it is abandoned and the new transition starts from where it remained.

Any suggestions how cand I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iuliux,

The classic implementation to animate a transition in N steps is as follows:

```
for (i = 0;  i <= N;  ++i) {
  for (p = 0;  p < nPoints;  ++p) {
    pointsToDraw[p] = initialPoints[p] + (finalPoints[p] - initialPoints[p]) * i / N
  }
  drawFigureAt(pointsToDraw);
}
```

In English:

1. For each point, imagine a line between its initial and final positions.
2. Calculate points along the line that divide it into N segments of equal size.
3. Draw the figure using the first set of points, then the next, *etc.*

If the figure moves before you've drawn the final state, copy its current position into `initialPoints` and start the transition again.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's not that simple, it seems. If I do it this way, the image will distort very badly during the transition.

Comment: Double-check your code, and be sure each initial point corresponds to the proper intermediate and final points.  We'll be better equipped to help if you post your code.

Comment: I mean if the intermediate points are on a straight line from source to destination and each point does it's own independent transition, the image might get distorted along the way. Though, I abandoned this, I did it in a much simpler way in the end. Anyway, I accepted your answer and thanks for your time.

Comment: @iuliux,can you finish this,if you can  canyou share your code?

Comment: @iuliux: Now we're all curious!  How did you end up implementing this?  Also, did you try the linear interpolation?  It's a standard technique, so I'm wondering how the image distorted.

Comment: I didn't do it like this after all, I simplified it because the distortion and rotation was only eye-candy, so I kept the rectangle intact and reduced the problem to one single point. Sorry :)